# How to log a user out at a certain time of day

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

could someone please point me in the right direction?
I am not sure how to get started.

Our site uses passport.js to log users in.

I need to allow users to only be logged in during business hours like 7AM to 7PM

This is really the part I don't know how to get started with -
The code would need to check the current time every few minutes to see if we need to log the user out.

Comment: First off, is this 7AM-7PM in the user's timezone or in the server's timezone?  What about different users in different timezones?

Comment: Right, I will have to consider that. Thanks.  I am just hoping someone can point me in the right direction to get started.

Comment: So, you don't even know the answer to that?  Because if it's server-time (same times for all users), then one simple piece of middleware (only a few lines of code long) will handle it all.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an authentication concern or an authorization concern?

***Authentication*** is validating *who* a user is - their identity

***Authorization*** is validating that an authenticated user is *allowed* to perform a certain action.

It sounds like you're trying to limit access outside of business hours. Best practice would be to leave users logged in (authentication is still valid) but deny then access (remove their authorization) outside of business hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248758/discussion-between-kenny-johnson-and-jfriend00).